# Setting index as multindex format without being multindex

Tags: python, pandas

I have this data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'X1':[0,5,4,8,9,0,7,6],
                   'X2':[4,1,3,5,6,2,3,3],
                   'X3':['A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C']})    
df = df.set_index('X3')
```

I want to set `X3` as index so I would do:

```
df = df.set_index('X3')
```

And the result is:

[image]

However, I'm looking to set the same index but as a multi-index format (even if it's not a multi-index). This is the expected result:

```
    X1 X2 
A   0  4  
    5  1  
B   4  3  
    8  5  
    9  6  
C   0  2  
    7  3  
    6  3
```

Is that possible?

**EDIT**

Answering the comments, the reason I want to achieve this is that I want to order `df` by `X1` values without losing "the grouping" of `X3`, so I would be able to see the order in each `X3` group. I can't do it with `sort_values(['X3', 'X1'], ascending=[False, False])` because **the first condition of sorting must be the maximum of each group keeping all rows from the same group together**. So I can see the group that has the maximum X1 and immediately see how are the other values of the same group, then the second group contains the second maximum of X1 and immediately see how are the other values of the second group, and so on.

Comment: I am not sure why you would want to achieve such a result. At the end, index should be unique. You might want to use `group_by` instead.

Comment: What you want doesn't make much sense. You seem to confuse display and data. What is your underlying goal?

Comment: I have explained in the edit. Let me know if I'm not clear yet

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps; but what if you first get rid of repeated values from 'X3' columns then set that as index...

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({'X1':[0,5,4,8,9,0,7,6],
                   'X2':[4,1,3,5,6,2,3,3],
                   'X3':['A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C']})    

lst_index = [] 
for x in df["X3"]:
    if x in lst_index:
        lst_index.append("")
    else:
        lst_index.append(x)

del df["X3"] # delete this column if not required anymore...
df.index = lst_index

# Output

    X1  X2
A   0   4
    5   1
B   4   3
    8   5
    9   6
C   0   2
    7   3
    6   3
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
df
    X1  X2  X3
0   0   4   A
1   5   1   A
2   4   3   B
3   8   5   B
4   9   6   B
5   0   2   C
6   7   3   C
7   6   3   C

df = df.set_index('X3')
new_index = pd.Series([i if not j else '' for i, j in list(zip(df.index, df.index.duplicated())) ])
df = df.set_index(new_index)

    X1  X2
A   0   4
    5   1
B   4   3
    8   5
    9   6
C   0   2
    7   3
    6   3
```